# Загрузка изображений в combobox без скачивания их на диск

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Надо скачать изображения с сервера и поместить их в QIcon в QCombobox, используется PyQt5. Надо что бы они хранились в оперативной памяти, а не загружались на жёсткий диск.

```
for i in parser.player_technique().tank_id_list():
    rs = requests.get(parser.tanks_list(str(i)).images()['contour_icon'])

    file_name = parser.tanks_list(str(i)).images()['contour_icon']
    out = open(file_name, mode="wb")
    self.players_tech.addItem(QIcon(out.write(rs.content)), ' ' + parser.tanks_list(str(i)).name())
```

Comment: Этот код рабочий? `write` вернет количество записанных байтов, а `QIcon`  в конструкторе вряд ли такое ожидает... Да и в следующий раз лучше прикладывайте минимальный пример, чтобы можно было его запустить и оттестировать

Comment: Кст, а можете ссылку скинуть? Интересно стало что там такое с танками :)

Comment: Это картинки с контурами танков из WoT c серверов Wargame. Пример вывода словаря parser.tanks_list(tank_id).images() {'big_icon': 'http://api.worldoftanks.ru/static/2.56.0/wot/encyclopedia/vehicle/france-F13_AMX38.png', 'small_icon': 'http://api.worldoftanks.ru/static/2.56.0/wot/encyclopedia/vehicle/small/france-F13_AMX38.png', 'contour_icon': 'http://api.worldoftanks.ru/static/2.56.0/wot/encyclopedia/vehicle/contour/france-F13_AMX38.png'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вариант с сохранением файла и последующим его удалением:

```
for i in parser.player_technique().tank_id_list():
    file_name = parser.tanks_list(str(i)).images()['contour_icon']
    with open(file_name, mode="wb") as out:
        rs = requests.get(parser.tanks_list(str(i)).images()['contour_icon'])
        out.write(rs.content)
    
    icon = QIcon(file_name)
    name = ' ' + parser.tanks_list(str(i)).name()
    self.players_tech.addItem(icon, name)
    
    os.remove(file_name)
```

---

**Вариант без сохранения в файл.**

Согласно [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qicon.html#QIcon-2) у `QIcon` нет конструктора, который принял бы байтовый массив, но есть возможность передать `QPixmap`. Если посмотреть в конструкторы `QPixmap`, то и там нет байтового массива, зато среди его методов есть [loadFromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-3), который принимает байтовый массив, теперь модифицируем код:

```
for i in parser.player_technique().tank_id_list():
    rs = requests.get(parser.tanks_list(str(i)).images()['contour_icon'])

    pixmap = QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(rs.content)        

    icon = QIcon(pixmap)
    name = ' ' + parser.tanks_list(str(i)).name()
    self.players_tech.addItem(icon, name)
```